# Is CGI script a separate scripting language?

Tags: perl, cgi

I am new with scripting languages and we will be starting some CGI scripts in September. I am confused between CGI and Perl.

Are they same, or these are two different languages?

Comment: You could've just googled it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

Comment: By the way, where will you be "starting some CGI scripts in September"? That is not a sane way to write web applications in 2016. You should look at [PSGI/Plack](http://plackperl.org/) instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) is not a programming language.

CGI is a protocol used by web servers to delegate the handling of an HTTP request to a program that is executed for that express purpose. It allows for dynamically generated web pages.

While Perl is a common choice, the program handling the request for the web server can be written in any language.

Answer (score 4):

As [RFC 3875](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875) explains:

> The Common Gateway Interface (CGI) is a simple interface for running external programs, software or gateways under an information server in a platform independent manner.  Currently, the supported information servers are HTTP servers.
>
> The interface has been in use by the World-Wide Web (WWW) since 1993.

CGI programs can be implemented in any language, compiled or interpreted so long as they conform to the interface.

There have been attempts at updating the CGI spec, first to [1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-robinson-www-interface-00), then to 1.2, but I believe both have been aborted. [W3C's CGI page](https://www.w3.org/CGI/) has some links of historical interest.

Answer (score 3):

No. CGI ist not a language. It's merely an agreement on how webservers (e.g. Apache) and *"programs"* on the server interact. These *"programs"* may be written in any language you like, be it Perl, PHP, Python, or even C/C++.

For example, when you call the URL *http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/myscript?parm1=X&parm2=Y* then the webserver (Apache for that matter) executes the program "myscript" and somehow feeds the parameters "parm1" and "parm2" (together with their values X and Y) to that program. This might be as environment variables or as STDIN.

CGI defines *how* the variables (amongst other things) are interchanged and *how* the program returns its results.

The program itself may be written in any language you want, as long as Apache can execute it.

Very often these CGI programs are actually scripts (as opposed to compiled binaries), thus the commonly used term "cgi script".

Comment: Actually, it has nothing to do with the clients.  It is an interface specification between the web ***server*** (i.e Apache, nginx, etc) and user programs that can be executed by and on the server to respond to requests from clients.

Comment: Yes, @JimGarrison, you are right. The clients aren't really involved in CGI (despite they initiate the request). I just wanted to make clear that CGI is not another language but show the overall context. I'll try to fix my answer.

Comment: @JimGarrison I updated my answer and dropped the reference to the clients. // btw: the question is a bit OT anyway but I didn't want to flag it as such. I think it does no harm to give the OP an idea what CGI is about.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason for the confusion is that in the second half of the 1990s, as CGI started to become very popular, Perl was the language that was probably most commonly used to write CGI programs. This meant that the two terms became inextricably linked in some people's minds.

In fact I have heard people say that only Perl can be use to write CGI programs and that CGI programming is the only thing that Perl can be used for. Neither of these statements are true.